# Reading a csv file in pyspark (1.6.0)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Maybe the question is trivial but i am getting issues while reading a csv from local directory in Pyspark.

I tried,

```python
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark import SparkContext as sc
mydata = sc.textFile("/home/documents/mydata.csv")
newdata = mydata.map(lambda line: line.split(","))
```

But getting a error like,

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method textFile() must be called with SparkContext instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

Now my question is I have called `SparkContext` just before that. Then why am I getting such error? Please guide me where I am lacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not `import SparkContext as sc`:

- In [*interactive* usage](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/quick-start.html#interactive-analysis-with-the-spark-shell) (i.e. pyspark shell), `sc` is already initialized, so `sc.textFile()` should work fine
- In [self-contained applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/quick-start.html#self-contained-applications), you should initialize `sc` first:

  ```python
  from pyspark import SparkContext
  sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
  ```

where the arguments in `SparkContext()` matter - see the provided links for more details.

Finally, Spark 1.x cannot natively read CSV files into dataframes - you will need the [Spark CSV](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) external package. You may find a relevant [blog post](https://www.nodalpoint.com/spark-dataframes-from-csv-files/) I wrote some time ago for Spark 1.5 useful...